# Let $\langle G , *\rangle$ be an Abelian group with the identity $e$, Let $H = \{x \in G \mid x^2 = e\}$. Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory

The question asks for:

> Let $\langle G , *\rangle$ be an Abelian group with the identity $e$. Let $H = \{x \in G \mid x^2 = e\}$. Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Based on what I know, $H$ contains $e$. Take $x,y\in H$. It is sufficient to show that $xy^{-1}$ belongs to $H$. By definition, this means that you have to check that $xy^{-1}xy^{-1}=e$. But you know that $G$ is abelian and that $x^2 = e$, $y^2 = e$.

But I an not sure if this is entirely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's almost done:
$$
xy^{-1}xy^{-1}=xxy^{-1}y^{-1}=x^2(y^{-1})^2=x^2(y^2)^{-1}=\dots
$$
In the first equality you apply the hypothesis that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: So what I was missing is that property yes?